# Cheapest US car rental with CDW/LDW for an European (German) under 24

Tags: usa, car-rentals, payment-cards, german-citizens

The situation is as follows:

- My girlfriend and I (24 and 22) are going on holiday for 28 days
- We're starting and finishing our trip in Las Vegas
- We want to rent a car for those ~27 days and have a CDW insurance
- I have a company code at National/Enterprise which won't charge an underage fee (so I could get a car for about $800)
- National offers (only) LDW, but it is very expensive (another $800)

So I was wondering whether there is a cheaper way to get a CDW/LDW (both of us are German). Perhaps either a suitable credit card or some third-party insurance? The price of $800 seems incredibly high to me.

What is the best practice in that case?

Comment: Get it third party. There are loads of "car hire excess" insurers out there.

Comment: Any recommendations? (From a stranger in the internet :D)

Comment: Or book it from a European website, it might be directly included and cheaper. In general, spend time comparing prices.

Comment: Well then I couldn't profit from the code anymore

Answer (score 2):

Some possible strategies include:

1. Check the figures from national. $800 for 28 days CDW seems excessive, but maybe that's how they are compensating for giving you a deal on driver age.
2. If you have auto-insurance at home, see if they will add worldwide coverage for rental cars to your policy. If they do it will be less than $800.
3. Get separate insurance to cover rental vehicles. There are plenty out there, and none are as expensive as $800.
4. Find a credit card that offers CDW as a perk if you rent the car with it. In North America there are plenty such cards, with fees much less than the cost of CDW.

Comment: 1. This is $30/day, I found a website saying, that this is the maximum allowed amount. 2. Not the case. 3. Are they reliable? Any long and well known, reliable names? 4. We'll probably do that... Will I have to take photos of the whole car when renting in order not to get ripped off?

Comment: 4. No, that is only in Germany, where they charge you for every ant bite. In the US, when any damage is smaller than 15 cm diameter, it is ignored.

Comment: There are stories of people being charged for non-existent or pre-existing damage in North America. Taking photos of the car before and after is a wise precaution anyway.